# How to center divs with images in another div?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with centering .social divs in outer div. I was searching an answer but I can't find a working solution. Here's HTML:

```
<div class="socials">
  <div class="social">
    <img src="images/fb.png">
  </div>
  <div class="social">
    <img src="images/insta.png">
  </div>
  <div class="social">
    <img src="images/tt.png">
  </div>
  <div class="social">
    <img src="images/snap.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.social {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

I want to .social divs are next to each other and centered to .socials div.

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/n4f3xuv8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help, give this try.

```css
.social {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table-cell;
}

.socials {
  display: table;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="socials">
  <div class="social">
    <img src="images/fb.png">
  </div>
  <div class="social">
    <img src="images/insta.png">
  </div>
  <div class="social">
    <img src="images/tt.png">
  </div>
  <div class="social">
    <img src="images/snap.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the answer you are looking for. Do this in your css

```
.social {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.socials{
  text-align:center;
}
```

Click [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WjqgLg) to see the codepen

Comment: I try this earlier but it's not working for me. In my opinion this works when we have a text in divs but not images or empty space. However thanks for trying to help me :)